# What is the Difference between Angular Js, Angular 1,2,3 and 4 ?

Tags: angularjs, angular

From where I should start reading if I want to know completely about angular ? Need Answers in detail.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, u should start at Angular2. as it very different and faster than angular 1. the later versions of angular are similar to AngularJs2.

Comment: https://angular.io/  A great place to start

Comment: @Naruto Is there any specified materials for it ?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni It is common for angular js and Angular 2 ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was confused, thats why..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask a specific question about what you are confused by. There are thousands of articles regarding the move from AngularJS to Angular, for instance.

Comment: @PadmeshKannan , in my opinion , if you are thinking about starting to learn Angular you should only focus on version 2 and above which is a complete rewrite of the framework. Angular.js is a thing of the past by now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*AngularJS* and all *Angular* versions are Javascript web frameworks to create web applications, in particular single-page apps.

*AngularJS* is the first version of the framework. Therefore, it's the same as *Angular 1*. While it's still rather popular, it won't receive any major functional updates anymore and is in long-term support mode. The framework is documented on the [AngularJS web site](https://angularjs.org/).

*Angular 2* was a complete re-write of the framework. Even though it shares part of the name and many concepts, it's incompatible with AngularJS and upgrading to Angular 2 or higher requires to more or less re-write the application.

*Angular 2* has since evolved and versions 3, 4, 5 and 6 have been released. They are very similar to Angular 2 and upgrading from Angular 2 to 6 is straight-forward. Angular 6 is documented at [angular.io](https://angular.io/).